# await with lambda expressions only

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax inorder to use await with lambda expressions (anonymous lambda methods). All examples seem to use actual methods declared with the async keyword. Let me describe what I want:

```
...code in UI thread...
Customer cust = null;
using (DataContext context = new DataContext()) // I want to run this async
{
   cust = context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
}
...continue code in UI thread...
```

Inorder to not block the UI thread during the database query, I would write:

```
...code in UI thread...
Customer cust = null;
Task.Run(() => 
{
   using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
   {
      cust = context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
   }
});
...continue code in UI thread...
```

This would not work of course, because the UI thread would continue after the task had been started. I cannot `Wait()` on the `Task`, because that would block the UI thread. Simply adding `await` in front of `Task.Run()` does not compile. The best thing that I could come up with was:

```
...code in UI thread...
Customer cust = null;
Parallel.Invoke(async () =>
{
   await Task.Run(() => 
   {
      using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
      {
         cust = context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
      }
   });
});
...continue code in UI thread...
```

Now I haven't tested this yet, so I don't know if this would even actually work or still block the UI thread. But I don't like the `Parallel.Invoke` call anyway, I'm sure there is a cleaner/nicer way of invoking the anonymous method, but at the moment I can't come up with anything. Also the main issue I have, is that my gut is telling me that inorder to achieve asynchronous continuation (invoke database query async, don't block UI thread during it, then continue with what ever code follows the async call on the UI thread), the very first line must start with **await ...**
Eg:

```
...code in UI thread...
Customer cust = null;
await ...(whatever follows)
...continue code in UI thread...
```

Or maybe even:

```
...code in UI thread...
Customer cust = await ...(some anonymous lambda method returning Customer)
...continue code in UI thread...
```

So my question is. How to correctly write this piece of code without using any named methods, only lambda expressions (anonymous lambda methods).

Comment: In what way does it not compile? Normally putting await before Task.Run shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @erikkallen - The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Then do what the error message suggests.

Comment: @erikkallen - not always possible. I specifically wanted to know how to achieve 'await' without modifying my outer handler/method (although I didn't mention this in my post, because I wasn't aware that was the only way of doing it). Sometimes you can't change your methods or handlers and as I found out, thanks to i3arnon discussion, in those cases you simply can't use 'await'.

Comment: @Marko I think you don't quite get the idea behind `await`. If you did, the constraints would be pretty obvious. And there's nothing preventing you from just writing an `async void` (or even `async Task`) method that you call from wherever you want - the caller of an `async` method does not necessarily have to be `async` itself. It's generally a bad idea, of course, but UI event handlers are actually the sole reason for the existence of `async void` methods. `async` is not part of the signature, it's just a hint to the compiler - the C# team is pretty big on maintaining compatibility.

Comment: And do note that not blocking the UI thread has its own problems - it opens you up to issues with interleaving work (one of the big reasons using `Application.DoEvents` is "tricky" - it's basically a very simple and limited version of `await` for UI). There's no silver bullets, you still need to know what you're doing.

Comment: @Luaan - unless I'm mistaken, the caller has to be async as well if it wants to await on the method, otherwise the call would end up being synchronous? Also, the sole purpose of async/await was to free up the UI thread inorder to make apps responsive, encoruage develeopers to use the simpler await style (the previous way of doing things with callbacks and delegates was such a hassle, that's way most people avoided asynchronous style all together). So why now is awaiting and not blocking the UI thread a bad idea?? Can you show some examples of problems with interleaving work or what you mean?

Comment: @Marko If he wants to `await` - but that's not necessary. You can still write `await`-based continuation workflows, without `await`ing the workflow itself. It's great to keep the UI responsive, sure - but it's not free. You need to understand that `await` doesn't mean you no longer need to care about synchronization or similar issues. Sure, it's easier to write asynchronous code with `await`, but it's just as easy to write *incorrect* asynchronous code with or without `await`. What if the user clicks a button while some async code is running based on different button click?

Comment: @Luaan - well that part I already have covered. I simply disable the window with all the controls inside of it and show the hourglass cursor. So the user cannot click on any other buttons during the asynchronous operation (the main thing is to avoid showing "this program has stopped working..."). The only real problem would be the user closing the window. But I have that covered as well, since I decided not to use await and simply stick to Task.Run -> after the database query Dispatcher.BeginInvoke -> first thing I check then is (PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) != null)

Comment: @Marko Yup, this is the way you usually use. Just make sure you don't forget to disable some tiny little annoying thing somewhere. It's quite easy to introduce such vectors by having multiple forms, for example. Or even other event sources, like timers, or DB notifications. I'm not saying you shouldn't do it - I'm just saying you should be careful. It's trickier than it looks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Task.Run` and `await` the returned task. You just need to mark this method with the `async` keyword and have it return a `Task`:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    Customer cust = null;
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
       using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
       {
          cust = context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
       }
    });
}
```

Now, if this is the top level UI event handler it can't return a `Task` and you need to use `async void`. This is only appropriate in UI event handlers.

If you can't make you method `async` and you still want to keep the operation asynchronous you can register the UI thread operations as a continuation with `ContinueWith` and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` to make sure the continuation runs on the UI thread:

```
void Foo()
{
    Customer cust = null;
    var task = Task.Run(() => 
    {
       using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
       {
          cust = context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == 1);
       }
    });

    task.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    {
        // ...continue code in UI thread...
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Let's assume that I can't declare my method with async. That I must follow void Foo(), but I still want to await inside of it, how would I go about that? Is something like Parallel.Invoke, which I came up with, the way to go or how would one Invoke an anonymous 'async () => { }' method?
Edit: .Single() is plain old simple LINQ2SQL which doesn't support async.

Comment: @Marko if your method can't be `async` then you can't use `await`. You can fire an `async` operation and block on it with `Task.Wait` or you can start it and move on without waiting for it at all. You can either wait synchronously, wait asynchronously or not wait at all, there are no other choices.

Comment: so if my top level handler, is a reagular WPF button_Click() handler, which I presume I can't make async. Then I simply move all my current code from inside the button handler to "async Task Foo ()" and inside the button handler just call "await Foo();"??

Comment: @Marko You can make `button_click` async. This is the UI event handler I mentioned. You should make it `async void` and use `await` inside it.

Comment: okay. For final clarification, if for some reason I can't make mark the handler as async (maybe a different scenario, or 3-rd party code or whatever), then I move my current code to "async Task Foo()" and then simply "await Foo();" like I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @Marko you can move the code over but you can't use `await Foo()` in the event handler. I added to the answer how you can `ContinueWith` instead of `await`.

Comment: @Marko If the method is a 3rd party method, then how in the world are you writing code as the implementation of that method?  If you're writing the code for that method, you can make it `async`.

Comment: I was already aware of task.ContinueWith(), but I can't use this because my database query is inside an if block and the thing that I need to continue with is outside of it. It would require some ugly restructuring to make it work. I was hoping the await keyword would have been the silver bullet, because it specifically doesn't require any such code changes, it automatically continues in your code where it left off. As for not marking the method async, I wanted to know this in principal, when and how I can use await. I'll look into if and how I can mark my method async...

Comment: @Servy - I might not have the full know-how of how and where you can apply async/await, so do pardon my ignorance. But if the EventHandler is specified by 3-rd party code, then I am the one writing the implemention for that handler method. When I subscribe to the event, I must specify a method that matches that EventHandler signature. If what I now understand is correct, I can add the async keyword to my method declaration willy-nilly without breaking the signature...

Comment: @Marko the `async` keyword is not a part of the signature. `async` can be applied to any method returning a `Task`, `Task<T>`, `void`. UI event handlers (and most if not all other events) return `void` and that's what `async void` is for.

Comment: @Marko Had you merely *tried* adding it, you would have found out that it wasn't a problem at all.

Comment: @Servy - while writing this post, I didn't know, that the only way to make this work was marking my own method async. I thought, surely I can simply invoke some anonym. method, mark IT as async, and let await do its magic (thus my question in this post) So no, I did not try making my method async because I thought it was not necessary, also I did not want to alter my method signature in fear of breaking stuff. And, during my discussion with i3arnon, I wanted to know, if there was any way I could make await work with this anonymous method without marking my method as async (whatever the reason)